# How to create a database for electron app from python

Tags: python, node.js, database, electron

I want to create a database with Python and then use this database in an Electron app.

There are a few requirements that I have:

1. The database shared should be in a file format
2. Ideally, the database created by Python can be used directly in Node without much trouble
3. The database is in some form of JSON

I've learned about `tinydb` for Python and it seems great. However, I'm having trouble to use the result in the Electron app since I can't find packages that can provide database-like operations on the JSON created by `tinydb`

Comment: Is there a reason why databases such as `MySQL` and `MongoDB` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @CosmosZhu I've looked around and found that having `MySQL` or `MongoDB` would mean the electron app can't be "portable" so that it can be distributed easily.

Comment: What about `sqlite` it stores the database in a file and both `python` and `node` have modules which can interact with a `sqlite` database.

Comment: @CosmosZhu `sqlite` does seem to work. Do you have other suggestions for a database that's also in JSON form like tinydb?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to create the database in Python? If using javascript to both create the database then the option to choose a database will be so much easier.

Comment: @CosmosZhu I've already implemented the processing stage by Python and only want to use it in electron. I guess it makes sense to port it into javascript so that the same database can be shared. Do you have any suggestion for a database for javascript that would serve the need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200572/discussion-between-cosmos-zhu-and-cosmos547).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is pretty much the 'go to' database for simple databases in Electron. It's proven and robust. SQLite 3.9 introduced a new extension (JSON1) that allows you to easily work with JSON data. It provides json_insert(), json_replace, and json_set() functions for JSON data.

There's a discussion here on HN about using the JSON1 extension in SQLite - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19277809